# C:\Windows\System32\ipconfig.exe console flashing frequently

Tags: windows-8.1

A black console window with the title `C:\Windows\System32\ipconfig.exe` keeps popping up on my screen. It appears for a second and then disappears. It is happening frequently. Pease help me fix it.

Comment: maybe task scheduler is making it appear.. it may help if you notice the date and time it does it and note them down until you spot a pattern..  It's tough to diagnose.. Ideally maybe there is a way to get it to stay there like making a cmd.exe that does cmd /k and then so it stays there

Comment: this is a good question, how to diagnose that cause of a flashing cmd.exe window in this case running ipconfig.exe

Comment: it's not malware behaviour, but there is a video discussing how to use process explorer (ignore the title of the video that menetions malware), and it may, possibly mention how to find the source of a window that pops up momentarily but i'm really not sure and it's a long video so probably not useful but anyhow, ..hunting by mark russinovich (author of process explorer) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wuy_Pm3KaV8